# Python iterate thru csv and execute point in polygon operation

Tags: python, pandas, gis, shapely

My goal is to iterate thru data frame from CSV file and perform a point in polygon operation and assign this to a new column in the data frame. I was able to construct function and my only problem is how to iterate thru data frame and append with results of the function.

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, shape
point = Point(10.2023019,8.43254802)
fc = fiona.open("ngaadmbndaadm2osgof20170222.geojson")
print (fc.schema)
```

and then print value for values from the point:

```
for feature in fc:
    if shape(feature['geometry']).contains(point):
                df_data['Admin2name'] = (feature['properties']['admin2Name'])
```

My data frame looks like this

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is usually not efficient to iterate through the dataframe. Instead you may want to read your csv file to a different dataframe and merge with your current dataframe on the X&Y coordinates columns.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution with another method executing spatial join (merge) on two geodataframes

```
merged_gdf = gpd.sjoin(gdf, df_lga, how="inner", op="within")
```

For others who will have this problem full code below

```
import pandas as pd 
import geopandas as gpd 
df_lga = gpd.read_file('ngaadmbndaadm2osgof20170222.geojson') #first df
df_data = pd.read_csv('nigeria_healthfacilities.csv', low_memory=False)# second df

geometry = [Point(xy) for xy in zip(df_data.X, df_data.Y)] # transpose lat, long to shapely geomentry point 
crs = {'init': 'epsg:4326'} #set crs
gdf = GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)

merged_gdf = gpd.sjoin(gdf, df_lga, how="inner", op="within")# merge two df into one that spatialy joins points in polygons 
merged_gdf
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, your question isn't very clear but I assume you're asking how to create a new column as a function of previous columns? You almost never want to iterate through all columns but if the Dataframe is small enough it won't matter of course.

You'll want to use vectorization if possible:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : [1,2,3,4,5,6], 'B': [6,5,4,3,2,1]})
df
>>>     A   B
    0   1   6
    1   2   5
    2   3   4
    3   4   3
    4   5   2
    5   6   1
```

Now you can simple define a new column directly from A and B:

```
df['C'] = (df['A']*df['B'] >= 8)
df
>>>     A   B   C
    0   1   6   False
    1   2   5   True
    2   3   4   True
    3   4   3   True
    4   5   2   True
    5   6   1   False
```

Or alternatively, use apply to apply a function:

```
df['D'] = df['B'].apply(lambda x: -x)
df
>>>     A   B   C        D
    0   1   6   False   -6
    1   2   5   True    -5
    2   3   4   True    -4
    3   4   3   True    -3
    4   5   2   True    -2
    5   6   1   False   -1
```